# run not responding for android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am updating an Android project, and for some reason the run button in eclipse does nothing.  I can get the app to run if I go Run>>Run Configurations... and then start it from that, but if I just click the play button or if I use the hotkey for run (`CTRL + F11` ) then nothing happens.  It seems to make no difference if an emulator is already going or not.

Anyone have suggestions?  I like to code by making small changes and then running the app to see what happened and its very frustrating to have to go through 3 clicks just to get it to run every time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using default settings in Eclipse, the Run button and hotkey `CTRL + F11` will not work when the xml editor is in focus. It should work if you are working with the Java editor. To use the button or hotkey while editing xml, first click on the project in the package explorer.

Comment: wow that did the trick.  Is there a way to make it work when the xml editor is in focus?

Comment: Not that I have found so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust this by going in to Eclipse Preferences and choosing Run/Debug and make it launch your last used Run Configuration. Then only for the first time you launch you will be required to right click your project and choose Run As -> Android Application. After doing this pressing Ctrl+F11 or the Run icon will always start that Run Configuration.